# Custom Profile Center for Multi-Org Connect for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are upgrading to Multi-Org soon and I would like to know how can I create a Custom Profile Center.

The documentation does explain one way [Custom Profile Center](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm?search_text=custom%20profile%20center)

Is that the only way or any simpler method as well? I want it only for Multi-Org. No other need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other easy way to create the custom profile center is to use microsites.

And for one click unsubscribe you can use a unsubscribe personalization string or API ampscript

Comment: Thanks Vishnu! Another related Q I have - So this microsite's URL will be embedded in the emails for customers to Manage preferences. Right ? How will the one click unsubscribe work in this case? Will I have to use the same standard Unsubscribe URL ?

Comment: yes the microsites url will be embeded in the emails for customers to manage preferences. The one click unsubscribe can be achieved in two ways.1. standard unsubscribe url(I believe we can do this, didnt test it though )2.Using custom code(Ampscript)you should be able to do it easily.